# How can I downgrade Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu-10.10

Since I upgraded Ubuntu from 10.10 to 11.04, I am facing much instability in display. Its very difficult to work with. Before upgrade it was working properly. Now even 10.10 version is giving flickers in displaying any pop-up window. I just want to roll back all the upgrades.

Answer (score 0):

This is answered in the [Ubuntu Downgrade Howto](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DowngradeHowto).